# HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized WCF & IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, iis

"You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers" is all I have been seeing for the last hour.  Ran into this issue when using WCF Web services and EF 5.

At first, the web service worked fine when returning simple data eg: `return "me"`, but right after I add EF and start using it to pull the data, all of sudden, IIS is requesting me to authenticate.  When I enter my creds it basically rejects then for no reason.  The app pool and file permissions all run under my creds for testing, which this doesn't occur with any other application with the same criterion.

So has anyone ran into this?  If I remove EF it works fine again, but I haven't the foggiest idea what part could possible cause IIS suddenly start forcing me to enter creds.

Comment: Did you try to set a breakpoint and see if your server side code is ever hit when you are using EF? What exactly changes do you make to hook up EF to your service? To me it's really strange that it may cuase this kind of exception.

Comment: @MaksymStrukov Yes, but the break point doesn't reveal anything.  I ended up re-installing IIS and now it works fine.